# How do I code jumpmenu to change font-family of targeted div using jquery?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I need to make a jump menu with several options of different font-families to choose from. When a user selects an option, the text within the targeted div changes to that font-family.

Here's an example that I got to work using anchor text links, but I would like to do the same thing using select/option:

http://jsfiddle.net/jesseislil/wYpvN/3/

Answer (score 0):

Updated version http://jsfiddle.net/wYpvN/4/